# Can I access an outer class instance from an instance of that outer classes inner class anonymously?

Tags: java, c#, nested-class

Java Pseudo Code

```
public class Foo{
    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("Kill all humans...");
    }
    public class Bar{
        public Bar(){
            Foo.this.doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

You can have a nested class access it's outer class instance through `<Class Instance>.this`, to look properties or variable values or even invoke methods if you wanted WITHOUT having to pass a reference of the outer class instance to the inner class instance (I'm assuming that is the anonymous part?).

Does C# have something equivalent?

Comment: You can write Foo.doStuff() if doStuff method will be static

Comment: yeah but in my case neither the parent nor the child class will be static, nor will any of their variables or what have you.

Comment: This is not a parent-child relationship. This is an outer-inner class relationship. Parent-child refers to inheritance.

Comment: I will edit, thank you.

Comment: Additionally to duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class covers difference between nested (no direct C# equivalent) vs static nested (close to C# nested class) in Java.

Comment: Side note: There is generally no need to express additional emotions (especially in ALL CAPS) in SO questions unless it directly related to problem.